# Multi-user/role testing, best practices

Tags: users, testing

Am loving using Drupal 6 for creating a site with more than one user "type", with different Content Profiles, different Roles with associated Permissions, different access to nodes etc. My current site has 3 different roles - Recruiters, Candidates and a Simple Administrator (as a reduced feature subset administrator, to limit the amount of damage that a non-technical administrator can do to the site, yet still do things like edit the outgoing emails, add/remove users etc).

I was wondering... when I am testing, I am currently using multiple browsers (dev in Firefox, Testing one user type in Chrome, one in ie9) to get around the "current" session issue (you can only be logged in as one user). What techniques do people use to test on multiple roles simultaneously? Is there, for example, a Firefox plugin or something else to isolate different browser based session cookies in different tabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the [Masquerade module](http://drupal.org/project/masquerade) for Drupal.  It allows you to switch users if you have the right permissions, so you could switch mid-session to a user with a different role etc.

Another thing you could try, though non-Drupal, is multiple sessions within Firefox.  Look [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11146/how-can-i-have-multiple-sessions-in-ff-without-using-profiles), [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1688469) and [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) to see if that could help you.

Comment: Criag, I noticed that you've asked 7 questions in the last week and haven't marked any with accepted answers, even though all of your questions have been answered.

If any of the answers have worked for you, could you please mark them as the correct/accepted answer?

Comment: My apologies Jamie, am rushed off my feet and trying to do too many things at once. I haven't had the chance yet to test many of the suggestions by other authors, as some of the work has been postponed due to the complications I am facing, specifically the apache solr views questions. I will do what I can to clean up the others.

Comment: No problem at all, I hope you figure out the issues mate.