# Is there a way to test or spoof different user access?

Tags: users, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-user/role testing, best practices](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/multi-user-role-testing-best-practices)

My current style in testing different user access is opening a different browser or opening a private session and logging into a different user.

Is there a way to spoof the current logged in user's identity? For example, I am logged in as Admin (user 1) and I want to see the site as regular user (ie, user 23). Is there a way I can do that in place within the same browser window/tab?

Comment: you can check this answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/multi-user-role-testing-best-practices

Comment: Thank you! I will mark this as duplicate of that question.