# Permissions filter like module filter

Tags: users

The [module filter](http://drupal.org/project/module_filter) makes managing modules from the UI very easy to manage. Live update with the search query and grouping. I've been looking for a similar module for the more messy permissions table. A similar module would definitely make it easier to manage that monstrous table :D

**Does anybody know if a module exists for this?**

I did try searching but I might not have used the right terms just like when [I searched for user spoof and it resulted to a module named Masquerade](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59313/is-there-a-way-to-test-or-spoof-different-user-access).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Fast Permissions Administration](http://drupal.org/project/fpa) module is the closest equivalent that I've found

> This module is here to alleviate frustration when trying to manage permissions in Drupal. By providing a better permissions interface hopefully a few innocent keyboards and mice can be saved.

You get a UI like:

[image]

Comment: I've proposed a feature request on this Fast Permissions Administration module (which works for Drupal 8, 9, and 10 now) to have an option to be much more like the simple module filter: https://www.drupal.org/project/fpa/issues/3354083

(Realizing that with module filter in core their *must* be an active core issue to do similar on the permissions page…)

Answer (score 4):

The 2.x branch of Module Filter includes a filter on the permissions page. By default it filters on the name of the module rather than the permission, but if you want to search by permission you can use a query prefixed with "perm:", e.g., perm:administer.

The available updates page also has a filter.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [Filter Permissions (filter_perms)](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_perms) module.

Both this and the accepted answers are good solutions, I think for Drupal 7 (no need to change the accepted answer). I think the difference between [Filter Permissions (filter_perms)](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_perms) and [Fast Permissions Administration fpa](https://www.drupal.org/project/fpa) is that the filtering provided by the fpa module is mainly (or perhaps totally) client-side based (I am guessing possibly that the entire module list is in the browser and client-side code provided with fpa filters this (perhaps using JS etc)). Whereas with filter_perms, the filter is submitted to the server-side, to the module in the Drupal site code which returns a filtered list.

My comparison of both is based on the following references:

from https://www.drupal.org/project/fpa :-

> **Optional integration with Filter permissions:**
>
> If you have a large number of permissions and roles, you might
>   experience memory limit issues when accessing the permissions page
>   that FPA is not designed to handle.
>
> If you are experiencing these issues, it is suggested that you install
>   the Filter permissions module along side FPA.

from: https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_perms :-

> If you aren't having performance issues due to massive
>   permissions/roles and want a nice filtering solution that works
>   entirely client side, Fast Permissions Administration is a slick
>   module that has a different approach than Filter Permissions but will
>   give similar benefits.

Also from my own experience of using filter_perms, the interface uses a html form based filter with a post to the server-side to send the filtering information.

As said, I think both modules are good solutions and therefore it would be for the site builder to choose.

The bottom line I think is that on the basis of being more client-side-based in filtering, fpa is the faster at filtering (as the name of the module suggests), but for sites with a large number of permissions it might not be scaleable if there are server-side memory limitations when rendering the page and also on the browser/client side if performance and memory there is limited.

Meanwhile although filter_perms might be perhaps a little slower as it uses a form submit to the server to filter, it would perhaps be more scaleable for a large amount of permissions if only the filtered subset are rendered on the server side and sent to be displayed in browser (e.g. out of memory fatal errors are less likely)

Both modules also have a Drupal 8 development branch, however I have not used this version at time of writing so could not advise on if there is available functionality in the Drupal 8 versions of the modules.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using now in Drupal 8 the [Permissions Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_filter) module

> The permission Filter module is a simple approach to provide a search
>   functionality in the people/permission page. It will help site admin
>   to get the desired result without scrolling down.

For Drupal 7 you have (apart the modules mentioned by other users) these modules:

[Dream permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/dream_permissions)

> This module facilitates the management of permissions, it allows you
>   to exclude roles and modules from the management screen.
>
> The management page uses ajax to load the relevant permissions, you
>   have to select at least one role and at least one module, otherwise
>   you don't get any results. Both roles and modules can be filtered to
>   make the selection easier.

[Permission Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/permission_select)

> Permission Select is a module that allows for quicker editing of role
>   permissions on /admin/user/permissions.
>
> The module utilizes jQuery to manipulate the DOM, creating links to
>   check all / uncheck all on each set of permissions for each module.
>   This allows for quicker manipulation of permissions for standard
>   users.

[Permissions Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/permission_grid)

> This gives an alternative way of administering permissions, by showing
>   those that form a related set in a grid of 'verbs' and 'objects'. For
>   example, for node permissions, this shows 'create', 'edit own', and so
>   on across the grid, and node types down the side.